# Send model attributes to Yii controller using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'm currently using the following code to send an Ajax get request to my controller:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink('clickMe', array('ajax'), array('update'=>'#results'));
```

This works fine, the controller receives the request and updates the view accordingly.

Now, I want to send in this request attributes of the model, i.e. from `model->getAttributes();`

How should I do this? Create a JSON object of the attributes and send that with the request?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass 'data' attribute and 'type' if needed:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink('clickMe', array('ajax'), array(
    'update' => '#results'
    'data' => CJSON::encode($model->attributes),
    'type' => 'post',
));
```

This code just replaces #results contents with json. If you need something different, use 'success' instead of 'update' like this:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink('clickMe', array('ajax'), array(
    'success' => 'function (response) {
            // do everything you need
    }',
    'data' => CJSON::encode($model->attributes),
    'type' => 'post',
));
```

Take a look at jquery ajax [options](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this works as far as json goes but for some reason the view doesn't update.  Still looking into that..

Comment: I updated my answer, check it. Or maybe you just dont have element with id="result"?